# Релизация смс-рассылки с помощью API smsc

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо реализовать смс-рассылку абонентам с помощью API [smsc](https://smsc.ru/).

Есть у меня две таблицы. В первую заносятся данные об абоненте: *логин, моб. телефон и тип подключаемой рассылки*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во второй к каждому типу рассылки прикрепляется характерное для него *сообщение*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Общая идея есть, но очень смутная и не факт, что правильная.

Выбираем *логин* абонента, проверяем каким-то условием какой *тип рассылки* для этого логина включен. Если включено, допустим, оповещение о *Приближении срока оплаты* - высылаем характерное для этого типа сообщение на *номер* абонента.

Вручную сообщение я высылал таким вот образом:

```
<script language=javascript>
    window.parent.location.href = "https://smsc.ru/sys/send.php?login=login&psw=psw&phones=$telephone&mes=$message";                             
</script>
```

Необходимо каким-то образом подставлять номера телефонов и сообщения для них. Но в силу своих скудных знаний - придумать как это сделать пока не могу. Очень надеюсь на помощь.

**UPD:**

Так я добавляю данные в первую таблицу:

```
$table = $system_site_prefix . 'erps_services_sms'; 
database_insert("INSERT INTO `$table` VALUES 
  (\"$index\", \"$abon_login\", \"$telephone\", \"$pay\", \"$orders\", \"$news\", \"$other\")");
```

Так во вторую:

```
$table = $system_site_prefix . 'erps_messages_sms'; 
database_insert("INSERT INTO `$table` VALUES (\"$index\", \"$group\", \"$title\", \"$message\")");
```

**UPD2:**

Структура таблиц:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше приведите примеры select запросов

Comment: Что именно? Для самой рассылки у меня почти ничего нет. Есть только как я с помощью JOIN склеил две таблицы и вывел все содержимое.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос структуры таблиц сервисов и сообщений. Я постараюсь в своем ответе привести пример структуры таблицы для связи сообщений и абоентов и запроса для скрипта отправки sms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = file_get_contents("https://smsc.ru/sys/send.php?login=login&psw=psw&phones=".urlencode($phones)."&mes=".urlencode($message));
```

Для того, что бы выбрать сразу абонентов с номерами и текстами сообщений, необходимо сделать join двух таблиц по типу отправляемого сообщения.

Для контроля кодов ответа сервера (200, 404, 403, etc...) лучше использовать curl в PHP

```
-- Структура таблицы для связи сообщений и абонентов
CREATE TABLE `erps_services_messages` (
  `index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

-- Запрос для выборки sms
SELECT
  sm.index AS `index`,
  m.message AS message,
  s.telephone AS telephone
FROM
  `erps_services_messages` AS sm
INNER JOIN
  `erps_messages_sms` AS m ON m.index = sm.message
INNER JOIN
  `erps_services_sms` AS s ON s.index = sm.service


+-------+----------------------+-------------+
| index | message              | telephone   |
+-------+----------------------+-------------+
|     1 | Сообщение 1          | +7999999999 |
|     2 | Сообщение 3          | +7999999999 |
|     3 | Сообщение 1          | +7888888888 |
|     4 | Сообщение 4          | +7888888888 |
+-------+----------------------+-------------+



-- После успешной отправки сообещния просто выполните
DELETE FROM `erps_services_messages` WHERE `index` = %

-- Пример заполнения данными моих тестовых таблиц
select * from erps_messages_sms;
+-------+----------------------+
| index | message              |
+-------+----------------------+
|     1 | Сообщение 1          |
|     2 | Сообщение 2          |
|     3 | Сообщение 3          |
|     4 | Сообщение 4          |
+-------+----------------------+

select * from erps_services_sms;
+-------+-------------+
| index | telephone   |
+-------+-------------+
|     1 | +7999999999 |
|     2 | +7888888888 |
+-------+-------------+

select * from erps_services_messages;
+-------+---------+---------+
| index | service | message |
+-------+---------+---------+
|     1 |       1 |       1 |
|     2 |       1 |       3 |
|     3 |       2 |       1 |
|     4 |       2 |       4 |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

Для добавления команды на отправку sms достаточно просто создать запись в таблице erps_services_messages и указать index из таблицы абонентов и index из таблицы сообщений. Скрипт отправки sms можно запускать по крону.

Comment: Добавил запросы, с помощью которых я добавляю абонента и сообщения к типам рассылок.

Comment: Добавил структуру таблиц

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за помощь и такой развернутый ответ, буду разбираться. Ответ пока помечать не буду, но чуть позже обязательно помечу. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

У них есть класс на PHP для работы с их сервисом, можно его использовать. 
Логин и пароль добавите свой.

```
<?php    

class Sms
{
    const login = "";
    const pass = "";
    const post = 1;
    const https = 1;
    const charset = "utf-8";
    const from = "support@example.com";
    const debug = 1;

    public function SendSmsWorld($phones, $message, $translit = 0, $time = 0, $id = 0, $format = 0, $sender = "example.com"", $query = "")
    {
        static $formats = array(1 => "flash=1", "push=1", "hlr=1", "bin=1", "bin=2", "ping=1");
        $m = $this->SmsSendCmd("send","cost=3&phones=".urlencode($phones)."&mes=".urlencode($message)."&translit=$translit&id=$id".
            ($format > 0 ? "&".$formats[$format] : "").
            ($sender === false ? "" : "&sender=".urlencode($sender)).
            ($time ? "&time=".urlencode($time) : "").($query ? "&$query" : ""));

        if (self::debug) {
            if ($m[1] > 0)
                echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно. ID: $m[0], всего SMS: $m[1], стоимость: $m[2], баланс: $m[3].\n";
            else
                echo "Ошибка №", -$m[1], $m[0] ? ", ID: ".$m[0] : "", "\n";
        }
        return $m;
    }


    public function GetSmsCost($phones, $message, $translit = 0, $format = 0, $sender = false, $query = "")
    {
        static $formats = array(1 => "flash=1", "push=1", "hlr=1", "bin=1", "bin=2", "ping=1");
        $m = $this->SmsSendCmd("send", "cost=1&phones=".urlencode($phones)."&mes=".urlencode($message).
            ($sender === false ? "" : "&sender=".urlencode($sender)).
            "&translit=$translit".($format > 0 ? "&".$formats[$format] : "").($query ? "&$query" : ""));

        // (cost, cnt) или (0, -error)

        if (self::debug) {
            if ($m[1] > 0)
                echo "Стоимость рассылки: $m[0]. Всего SMS: $m[1]\n";
            else
                echo "Ошибка №", -$m[1], "\n";
        }

        return $m;
    }

    private function SmsSendCmd($cmd, $arg = "")
    {
        $url = (self::https ? "https" : "http")."://smsc.ru/sys/$cmd.php?login=".urlencode(self::login)."&psw=".urlencode(self::pass)."&fmt=1&charset=".self::charset."&".$arg;
        $i = 0;
        do {
            if ($i)
                sleep(2);
            $ret = $this->SmsReadUrl($url);
        }
        while ($ret == "" && ++$i < 3);
        if ($ret == "")
        {
            if (self::debug)
                echo "Ошибка чтения адреса: $url\n";
            $ret = ","; // фиктивный ответ
        }
        return explode(",", $ret);
    }

    private function SmsReadUrl($url)
    {
        $ret = "";
        $post = self::post || strlen($url) > 2000;
        if (function_exists("curl_init"))
        {
            static $c = 0;
            if (!$c) {
                $c = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
                curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
                curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            }

            if ($post) {
                list($url, $post) = explode('?', $url, 2);
                curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
            }

            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            $ret = curl_exec($c);
        }
        elseif (!self::https && function_exists("fsockopen"))
        {
            $m = parse_url($url);
            $fp = fsockopen($m["host"], 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);

            if ($fp) {
                fwrite($fp, ($post ? "POST $m[path]" : "GET $m[path]?$m[query]")." HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: smsc.ru\r\nUser-Agent: PHP".($post ? "\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: ".strlen($m['query']) : "")."\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n".($post ? $m['query'] : ""));
                while (!feof($fp))
                    $ret .= fgets($fp, 1024);
                list(, $ret) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $ret, 2);
                fclose($fp);
            }
        }
        else
            $ret = file_get_contents($url);
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

После того как получите данные, уже в цикле можете проводить рассылку, вызывая метод **SendSmsWorld**

```
$sms = new Sms();
foreach ($arrListPhone as $r)
{
     $sms->SendSmsWorld($r['telephone'], $r['message'], 0);
}
```

Для большого количества номеров лучше использовать массовую рассылку одним запросом, не уверен точно есть у них эта возможность или нет, но вообще должна быть, где-то в документации нужно искать. Можно задать вопрос тех поддержке, они подскажут и ссылку скинут.

Comment: Пытался с помощью такого класса [SMSCenter](https://github.com/jhaoda/SMSCenter), но у меня слишком старая версия веб-сервера и старая версия php. Сайт, к которому пытаюсь это прикрутить сделан из говна и палок, но тут я, к сожалению, не в праве чему-то перечить, потому что основную часть делал не я. За ответ спасибо, попробую и вашим - вдруг получится.

Comment: С помощью этого класса все получилось. Большое спасибо.