# Обработка события в select

Tags: php, mysql

В форме есть `<select>` из четырех `<option>`

```
<select name=group size=1 onchange="">
    <option name="pay_op" value="Приближение срока оплаты">Приближение срока оплаты</option>
    <option name="orders_op" value="Технические работы">Технические работы</option>
    <option name="news_op" value="Новости компании">Новости компании</option>
    <option name="other_op" value="Прочая информация">Прочая информация</option>
</select>
```

`value` с него записывается в поле таблицы, структура которой вот такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В поле `index2` числа записывал вручную.

*А необходимо сделать так, чтобы при выборе `group` в `<select>` в базу автоматически отправлялось не только `value`, а так же соответствующий ему `index2`*.

То есть в форме я выбираю "Приближение срока оплаты" и вместе с этим в поле `index2` записывается "1", выбираю "Технические работы" - записывается "2" и т.д.

Может можно повесить на каждый `option` id-шник, и реализовать это с помощью `onchange`? Но пока что не представляю как именно.

**UPDATE:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выборка из таблиц:

```
$result = database_select("SELECT g.name AS group, m.title AS title, m.message AS message 
  FROM `vixen_erps_messages_sms` m
  INNER JOIN `vixen_erps_messages_group` g ON g.group_id = m.index2");
```

Comment: Так пишите в value option значение index2, его и пишите в бд. Group представьте как массив index2=>group и берите текстовые данные оттуда для отображения текста group

Comment: И вообще странная у вас структура бд. Создайте таблицу Groups, пишите в index2 group_id и выводите название группы оттуда, а не пишите id и название в одну таблицу.

Comment: У меня есть еще 2 таблицы, помимо этой. Это кстати относится к смс-рассылке с которой вы мне помогали. На основе этих индексов я выбираю группы к пользователям и отправляю смс конкретной группы пользователю. То есть этот index2 связывает 3 таблицы. Насчет массива не совсем понял, просто в value у меня само название и оно записывается в group.

Comment: А с какой целью Вы пишете в value название группы, а не ее индекс? Получается, таблица с группами есть? Если так, покажите, какие поля там есть и запрос, который отображает записи из таблицы из вопроса

Comment: Чтобы записать это значение в поле group. Просто по-другому не могу, знания пока очень слабые. Если я в value буду писать index2, то каким образом мне сформировать массив типов сообщений и писать их в поле group при выборе в select?

Comment: [Вот тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533642/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-api-smsc) видно 2 мои таблицы. А третья это та, которая связывает две первые, созданная по вашим советам. В третью я забиваю данные вручную, чтобы связать две первые и настроить рассылку, а нужно это автоматизировать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41207/discussion-between-ilyaplot-and-luckydutch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю HTML сделать таким

```
<select name=group size=1 onchange="">
    <option value="1">Приближение срока оплаты</option>
    <option value="2">Технические работы</option>
    <option value="3">Новости компании</option>
    <option value="4">Прочая информация</option>
</select>
```

Добавить таблицу с группами

```
group_id          name
1                 Приближение срока оплаты
2                 Технические работы
3                 Новости компании
4                 Прочая информация
```

Допустим, таблица из вопроса называется erps_messages_sms и выборка из этой таблицы примерно такая `select group, title, message from erps_messages_sms`

Удаляйте столбец group и приводите запрос к такому виду:

```
select 
    g.name as group, m.title as title, m.message as message 
from erps_messages_sms m 
inner join groups g on g.group_id = m.index2
```

На выходе получится тот же результат, как и в первом запросе

Comment: name из таблицы групп почему-то не вытаскивает. Таблицу groups сделал, из таблицы сообщений поле group убрал, запрос вроде составлен верно, как у вас. title и message выводится, а name - нет

Comment: Покажите данные первой и второй таблицы, а так же целиком запрос для выборки.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Видимо, проблема не в этой части

Comment: Запрос нормальный, должно работать

Comment: Решил проблему. Не туда запрос пихал.